# why it would be improper to compute and use test set means?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, training, validation

I have 2 questions regarding the whole subject of the data set in machine learning and I would be happy to receive an answer :)
1.Why it would be improper to compute and use test set means  and standard deviations?
2.Why we should limit how many times we use the test set, and that we should use the validation ?

Tanks a lot

Comment: Do you understand what overfitting is?

Comment: Yes, I know that there should be a separation between the training, validation, and test data so that the model can predict well and to avoid overfitting
But I didn't quite understand how it relates to questions 1,2.
What is meant by compute and use test set means? And why should we limit the use of the test set?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Why we should limit how many times we use the test set, and that we should use the validation ?

It is best practice to evaluate the test dataset only once because performance on the test dataset is the best estimate for the generalization ability of a trained model. Repeatably evaluating the test dataset encourages using different algorithms and hyperparameters to better fit the test data. Fitting to the test dataset may result in overestimating the generalization ability of the model.

> Why it would be improper to compute and use test set means ?

There are many ways to evaluate performance on the test dataset. Calculating mean performance can be one acceptable way. The mean is one of many ways to measure the central tendency for a group of data. There may be slices of the data that are more important, the mean does account for that.

Comment: Thank you all!
I edited question 1 - what about the standard deviation of the test?
Can it be said that the standard deviation of the test cannot be used because it is unknown? (since the data is unknown)

Answer (score 0):

The test set is intended for evaluation, i.e. testing how well the model works.

- In order to evaluate reliably, the information from the test set should not be seen before the actual testing, for the same reason that a student is not provided with the test questions in advance.
- A test set contains multiple instances. Again, this is required in order to evaluate reliably, since performance using only a few instances could be unreliable due to chance. But it's useful to keep in mind that the goal of a model is to predict for any *individual* instance. This implies that it doesn't make much sense to rely on some mean over instances in test set, since there might be a single instance in the set.
- The problem is not about reusing the test set, it's about deciding the value of a parameter (model parameter or hyper-parameter) based on this dataset. By definition if this happens this belongs to the training stage, otherwise the model would be fixed. Since usually a dataset is reused in order to change something about the model, this dataset is not a test set but a validation set.